# Is there a quicker way to enter every mail merge field when using Word's Mail Merge?

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

Is there a way to insert every field into a Word mail merge document without clicking Insert Mail Merge for each one. The source data is from an excel document and could potentially have a hundred fields which update each week.

Edit.
Example Excel Document.

```
Name   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
James  85  54  65      36  21  21
John   54  54  14  25  52  54  22
Hamish 41  21  12  35  22      99
```

I've used this Excel doc as data source in Word's Mail Merge for Emails.
I need the following result:

```
Name: James

1:85
2:54
3:65
5:36
6:21
7:21
```

I don't know how to automate the process as to insert each field name I have to click on the Insert Mail Merge and select the appropriate field. This is laborious with potentially hundreds of field names.

Macro result

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Dear "
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="Name"
    Selection.TypeText Text:=","
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="M_1"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="M_2"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="M_3"
End Sub
```

I can't think of a way to loop through each heading as the real headings aren't in a sequentially named order.

Comment: Try recording a macro when inserting a couple of field names to get the starting point. What you basically need to do is loop that collection. We need to see that macro code...

Comment: I've added the results of using a macro. I can't see how it can be used to iterate though each field heading as it uses the heading name every time it's added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the macro you recorded you'll see `ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields`. The `Fields` (plural) means this is a "collection". In many programming languages (including VBA) you can "loop" through a collection - which means you can use each individual item of the group. Recording a macro will give you information about how to address that group.

In the case of mail merge, there are two sets of "fields": those coming from the data source, and those already placed in the document. Your recorded macro give us the second. The designation of the first - what you need - is `DataFields`.

So in order "to insert each field name", as you ask:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim doc as Word.Document
  Dim dtField as Word.MailMergeDataField
  Dim sFieldName as String

  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  For each dtField in doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields
    sFieldName = dtField.Name
    doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=sFieldName
    Selection.TypeParagraph
  Next
End Sub
```